# Quotation marks in a multi-paragraph quote

Tags: quotation-marks

When quoting one person in a (long) multi-paragraph monologue (shortened here), should the ending quotation marks for one paragraph be omitted if the next paragraph starts with an attribution tag? I have not been able to find an answer to this anywhere.

"Everyone has to have a flag. <--- Quotation marks here, or not?

After a moment he added, "They were the only ones left."

Answer (score 2):

For the example you provided, you would need to provide closing quotations, because the person stopped speaking. "Everyone has to have a flag". After a moment he added, "they were the only ones left."

If it is a true multi-paragraph monologue you would however, only require one closing quotations at the end of the final paragraph.